# How can I tag an EC2 instance using Ruby in Chef?

Tags: ruby, amazon-ec2, chef-infra

I'm playing around with Chef to launch EC2 instances. Everything is working pretty well, but Chef doesn't seem to have the ability to tag the instances. Am I missing something?

Otherwise, what's the preferred Ruby library for achieving this? Can I do it without requiring additional gems?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Version 0.5.12 of the `knife-ec2` Gem supports tagging EC2 instances on creation with the `--tags` option.

```
knife ec2 server create [... your options...] --tags Tag=Value
```

Comment: Cool. Glad this is available now. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @jtimberman - So this tags the server in AWS but does it also tag the node in the context of Chef or do you have to do that in a separate command? Ie as you would manage tags on the node here: http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Managing+Nodes+With+Knife#ManagingNodesWithKnife-UsingTAGS

Comment: I am literally looking at the code here: https://github.com/opscode/knife-ec2/blob/master/lib/chef/knife/ec2_server_create.rb that enables tags yet when I run the

Comment: I got this working by doing the following: sudo bundle update; sudo bundle install; sudo gem uninstall knife-ec2 -v 0.5.4; That finally got tags working... Also it discovered it tags in ec2 only and not in chef. Finally as jtimberman mentioned the syntax is --tags attribute1=value1, attribute2=value2 .

Comment: Well, I want the tag to show up in my chef, this only tags the EC2 instance. :(

Answer (score 3):

Know this is old, but was browsing about and spotted it. Another alternative is to use the [AWS community cookbook](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/aws) - assuming you have key creds - if you want to do things programatically as part of the recipe.

```
aws = data_bag_item('mydatabag', 'creds')
aws_resource_tag node['ec2']['instance_id'] do
  aws_access_key aws['access_key']
  aws_secret_access_key aws['secret_key']
  tags({
    "foo" => "bar"
  })
  action :update
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually chef is used to install things on the instance. I'm not exactly sure how you start a node with chef, but maybe you can share this and I'll extend my answer?

Otherwise, [fog](https://github.com/geemus/fog) is a great library to do these things. I just skimmed over the source and it seems to support tagging as well.

To get fog: `gem install fog`.

Comment: This answer seems reasonable. I suspect that having chef auto-tag means providing code to the chef node, as well as the credentials of the AWS account to use the fog library to achieve this.

Comment: Correct. You'll need to distribute credentials to the node. I'd suggest to add a lock down AWS user account (using IAM) and pass it on to the instance via `user-script`.